# how to print the element of a specific index of a list in the visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a list
of contacts for example, and I want to print on the visualforce page only the contact in position 4 of this list, how can I do that?

Controller

```java
public List <contact> getContact(){ 
    if(contact == null){
        contact = [SELECT Id,contactId, Name
                   FROM Contact
                   WHERE OpportunityId =: idOpp
        ];
    }
```

Vsfp:

```html
<apex:variable value="{!0}" var="cont"/>
<apex:repeat value="{!Contact}" var="val">

    <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(cont==1,true,false)}"><!--I believe my error must be in this if-->
        Contact:
        {!val.Name}<br/>
        <apex:variable var="cont" value="{!(cont)+1}"/> 
    </apex:outputText> 
</apex:repeat>
```

it's working...but only for the element at position 0... I'm kind of lost on where to change to print elements from other positions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<apex:variable>` variables don't get reassigned inside of looping tags ([relevant documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_variable.htm)).

Whether you only want to display one index, or want to display all records but have one index display more information than the others, I'd recommend handling that in your controller/extension instead of trying to do it directly in the Visualforce markup.

If you really do only want to display the 4th entry in the list (index #3, because lists are 0-indexed), then it's as simple as using the square brace notation found in Apex (and other languages)

```
<apex:outputField value="{!contact[3].Name}" />
```

Alternatively, you could make a special getter to retrieve your target data (leveraging your existing getter) and keep the logic in Apex.

```
public Contact getFourthContact(){
    List<Contact> contacts = getContact();
    
    // This will fail if you don't have at least 4 contacts returned by getContact()
    return contacts[3];
}
```

In the case where you want to display all records, and more information for a single record, you'd probably want to have a small, inner class in your controller/extension to act as a wrapper class. You'd be able to store (and access in your VFP) a boolean (or an Integer) to indicate which record(s) to show different information on, and use that to drive the `rendered` attribute.

Comment: *variables don't get reassigned*, well, kind of. It's not officially supported, and I'd agree that it shouldn't be used, but it can sometimes be used if you understand the limitations.